# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the Unix & Linux community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant Unix & Linux conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: I get the impression that most users on U&L are end-people (developers *on* unix, sysadmins, hobbyists) rather than people who make unix and tend to speak at conferences (developers *of* unix, academics).

Comment: @gilles that's fine, we're just putting it out there as a possibility for the community